# AppleScript -- Is there any way to break line inside Array?

Tags: macos, syntax, applescript, macos-mojave

```
set docklist to { 15, "Mail" }
```

This works. But,

```
set docklist to {
    15,
    "Mail"
}
```

This doesn't. I added '\' as delimiter, but it doesn't work.

I need set a long array like below, so this is really important. Any help is appreciated.

```
set docklist to {
    "com.apple.mail", "file:///Applications/Mail.app/", 15, "Mail",
    "com.docker.docker", "file:///Applications/Docker.app/", 15, "Docker",
    "com.apple.AppStore", "file:///Applications/App%20Store.app/", 15, "App Store",
    "com.apple.dt.Xcode", "file:///Applications/Xcode.app/", 15, "Xcode",
    "com.amazon.Kindle", "file:///Applications/Kindle.app/", 15, "Kindle",
    "com.microsoft.VSCode", "file:///Applications/Visual%20Studio%20Code.app/", 15, "Visual Studio Code",
    "us.zoom.xos", "file:///Applications/zoom.us.app/", 15, "zoom.us",
    "com.hnc.Discord", "file:///Applications/Discord.app/", 15, "Discord",
    "com.panic.Transmit", "file:///Applications/Transmit.app/", 15, "Transmit",
    "org.virtualbox.app.VirtualBox", "file:///Applications/VirtualBox.app/", 15, "VirtualBox",
    "com.apple.QuickTimePlayerX", "file:///Applications/QuickTime%20Player.app/", 15, "QuickTime Player",
    "com.evernote.Evernote", "file:///Applications/Evernote.app/", 15, "Evernote",
    "com.mongodb.compass", "file:///Applications/MongoDB%20Compass.app/", 15, "MongoDB Compass",
    "com.google.android.studio", "file:///Applications/Android%20Studio.app/", 15, "Android Studio",
    "jp.naver.line.mac", "file:///Applications/LINE.app/", 15, "LINE",
    "com.getflywheel.lightning.local", "file:///Applications/Local.app/", 15, "Local",
    "com.sequelpro.SequelPro", "file:///Applications/Sequel%20Pro.app/", 15, "Sequel Pro",
    "com.tinyspeck.slackmacgap", "file:///Applications/Slack.app/", 15, "Slack",
    "com.apple.iCal", "file:///Applications/Calendar.app/", 15, "Calendar",
    "com.postmanlabs.mac", "file:///Applications/Postman.app/", 15, "Postman",
    "com.google.Chrome", "file:///Applications/Google%20Chrome.app/", 15, "Google Chrome",
    "com.adobe.xd", "file:///Applications/Adobe%20XD/Adobe%20XD.app/", 15, "Adobe XD",
    "com.apple.DigitalColorMeter", "file:///Applications/Utilities/Digital%20Color%20Meter.app/", 15, "Digital Color Meter",
    "com.apple.VoiceMemos", "file:///Applications/VoiceMemos.app/", 15, "Voice Memos",
    "com.runningwithcrayons.Alfred-Preferences", "file:///Applications/Alfred%204.app/Contents/Preferences/Alfred%20Preferences.app/", 15, "Alfred Preferences",
    "com.googlecode.iterm2", "file:///Applications/iTerm.app/", 15, "iTerm",
    "com.apple.Automator", "file:///Applications/Automator.app/", 15, "Automator",
    "com.apple.systempreferences", "file:///Applications/System%20Preferences.app/", 15, "System Preferences",
}
```

Comment: Add the `¬` character _(alt + return)_ at the end of each line instead of using \ - however the closing `}` will have to remain on the same line as the last list item. Btw, A list of list items is probably a better suited data structure for this kind of data, I'm sure it would make item access easier.

Comment: https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/AppleScript_Programming/Lists_and_records

Comment: While _lists_ are fine, note that trying to format _records_ like this won't work.

Comment: @red_menace umm, I know this little bit too hard, but I tried to use dictionary of list, Applescript doesn't support that....... Also, few documents exist. It's so pain to search many ways....

Comment: It does look like a list of records/dictionaries might be easier to group things together, but AppleScript pretty much refuses to let you use any kind of formatting for records unless you do something weird like append them, but then it turns into bracket hell (to get a list of records instead of merging them).

Comment: It's bracket hell but can't help it I guess.

Comment: @red_menace [Records can be formatted _reasonably_ well](https://forum.latenightsw.com/t/using-line-breaks-in-records/1520/8), by inserting the continuation character **before** the comma instead of after.

Comment: I'm writing that one down, although I don't know whether to laugh or cry.

Comment: @red_menace I share the sentiment.  I tend to do all my AppleScripting in `vim` nowadays, so I can format things however I please.